# Resizing .jpg image in asp.net and storing as stream

Tags: c#, image

I am resizing image in asp.net.I succeeded resizing image.but while converting it as stream
.jpg images are not working.

here my code
if i set image format as jpeg it is not working.Because in C# there is no image format for .jpg

```
 public static System.Drawing.Image ScaleImage(System.Drawing.Image image, int maxWidth, int maxHeight)
    {
        var width=image.Width;
        var height=image.Height;

        var newWidth=0;
        var newHeight=0;
        var divisor=0;
        if (width > height) {
                    newWidth = maxWidth;
                    divisor = width / maxWidth;
                    if (divisor == 0)
                    {
                        divisor = 1;
                    }
                    newHeight = Convert.ToInt32(height /divisor);
                }
                else {
                    newHeight = maxHeight;
                    divisor = height / maxHeight;
                    if (divisor == 0)
                    {
                        divisor = 1;
                    }
                    newWidth = Convert.ToInt32(width / divisor);
                }


        var newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);

        Graphics.FromImage(newImage).DrawImage(image, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
        return newImage;

    }

public static Stream ToStream(this System.Drawing.Image image, ImageFormat formaw)
    {
        var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        //stream.ReadTimeout = 100000;
        image.Save(stream, formaw);
        stream.Position = 0;
        //stream.ReadTimeout = 100000;
        return stream;
    }
```

Comment: You're not showing the call to `ToStream`, that would help, chances are you're passing in the wrong `ImageFormat`.

Answer (score 1):

Folks, ALL `System.Drawing` classes MUST be explicitly disposed if used in an ASP.NET service. **This is not optional. You WILL crash the server with any significant amount of traffic.**

Right now, your code is relying on the GC to deallocate the `Graphics` and `Bitmap` instance. Unfortunately, the GC views both objects as tiny, low-priority objects, and doesn't know they're actually taking up 100+ MB of RAM.

Here are some examples of how to do image resizing safely, and with better quality:

#### [LightResize](https://github.com/stakx/lightresize)

- [SinglePurposeResize.cs](https://github.com/stakx/lightresize/blob/dcee788b76fe5f3c8965f04066fd874a718723c9/SinglePurposeResize.cs)
- [LightResize.cs](https://github.com/stakx/lightresize/blob/dcee788b76fe5f3c8965f04066fd874a718723c9/LightResize.cs)

It's MIT-licensed, so no usage restrictions to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

The ImageFormat you are looking for is [ImageFormat.Jpeg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.imageformat.jpeg.aspx).